# How can I get the access token of my app so I can post on a page as a page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have an application which I use to post as a page on the Facebook page itself. I want to know how can I get the access token dynamically (because it expires every hours or 60 days).

Here's the code I use :

```
    $facebook = new \Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    ));

    try {
        $page_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");

        $page_info['access_token'] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // HERE'S THE PROBLEM !!
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
            'message'       => "My message !"
        );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a never expiring token for your page.

While making the request for :

```
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
```

use the long-lived token (that expires in 60 days) and you will get a **never**-expiring page access token.